# how to enable paypal express checkout as guest

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal lab Integration wizard to put express checkout work on my website. By default, if you don't have a paypal account you have to register on paypal then pay with credit/debit card. Is there a way to enable paypal express checkout as guest ? I am using .aspx (C#). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole` in your SetExpressCheckout API call.